# this.setState is only pulling last value in array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, nested

I'm VERY new to React and not sure how to render this nested array from an external JSON file. remittance is the only array here one that has nested values that I need to access and render. It logs to the console fine, but won't separate on setState. I apologize if this looks terrible.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data,
      rName: "",
      rDescription: "", 
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Mounted!");
    this.display();
  };

  display = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      var remittanceList = data[i].Remittance;
     // console.log(remittanceList);
      for (var x = 0; x < remittanceList.length; x++){
        var rName = remittanceList[x].PayorName;
        var rDescription = remittanceList[x].Description;
        console.log(rName + rDescription);
        this.setState({rName, rDescription});

      }
    }
  }


  render() {
    var { rName, rDescription } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Title/>
      {this.state.data.map((each, index) => (
      <PayInfo key={index}
        name={each.Payee.Name}
        fax={each.Payee.Fax}

        pan={each.Payment.PAN}
        cvv={each.Payment.CVV}
        exp={each.Payment.Exp}

        payorName={rName}
        description={rDescription}
      />
      ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

And the JSON file is something like this. Because the amount of remittances can very, I can't hardcode in an index to look for every time.

```
[
  {
    "Payee": {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "Fax": "5555555555",
    },
    "Payment": {
      "PAN": 123456,
      "CVV": 123,
      "Exp": "1/2018"
    },
    "Remittance": [
      {
        "PayorName": "Me",
        "Description": "Hello World.",
      },
      {
        "PayorName": "You",
        "Description": "Hey world.",
      },
      {
        "PayorName": "Snoop",
        "Description": "Bye world.",
      }
    ]
  },
```

And this is the PayInfo.js file I should've posted initially! Not sure if this changes any of the answer I got before?

```
import React from "react";
import "./PayInfo.css";

const PayInfo = props => (
<div>
    <div id="payee">
    <p>Payee</p>

        <p>{props.name}</p>
        <p>Fax: {props.fax}</p>

    </div>
    <hr></hr>

    <div id="payment">
        <p>Payment</p>
        <p>PAN: {props.pan}</p>
        <p>CVV: {props.cvv}</p>
        <p>Exp: {props.exp}</p>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>

    <div id="remittance">
        <p><strong>Remittance(s)</strong></p>
        <p>Payor: {props.payorName}</p>
        <p>Description: {props.description} </p>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
    <hr></hr>


</div>
);

export default PayInfo;
```

Comment: could you add code of `PayInfo` component

Comment: yes of course because your `setState` code written inside of forloop. Provide more details about your components or create some wokring fiddle. it will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your display method, you are setting the state inside for loop. so only the last value being set to the state. 
Please try the below code.

```
display = () => {
let totalRemittanceArray = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var remittanceList = data[i].Remittance;
  for (var x = 0; x < remittanceList.length; x++) {
    var rName = remittanceList[x].PayorName;
    var rDescription = remittanceList[x].Description;
    console.log(rName + rDescription);
    totalRemittanceArray.push({ rName, rDescription })
  }
}
this.setState({totalRemittanceArray})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is something like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/p36jlrz7jj

As you can see I extracted another component `PayerInfo`. Also React works perfect with map within the render method. I hope my example helps!

Currently you call setState in the for loop and thus overwrite the state every time, but I guess you figured that one out already. I use Array.map to loop over elements within JSX a lot. Dunno if one could do this more nicely, but there is always a possibility to improve ^^

A small improvement here: You could loop in a separate function first and then return the complete Array: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html

Comment: This way more readable and re-usable than what I had come up with. I will definitely remember this. THANK YOU!